# semidirect product of cyclic and p-groups

Tags: group-theory

How does conjugacy classes subgroups of a semi direct product  group cyclic group of order (q-1) where q is a power of p, look like?

Comment: The subgroups are the cyclic group of order (q-1) and p-group of order p where q is a power of prime p.

Comment: what have you attempted?